# Merge a svg file onto multiple tif files by scripting

Tags: svg, merge, photoshop, tiff, adobe-illustrator

I have a vector picture file (svg or Adobe Illustrator). This file is a "grid". I have over thousand tif pictures that I want to apply this grid onto.

Is there an easy automated way to do this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are loads of ways you could do this. I'd probably export the grid as a .tif file of the same dimensions and then use [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) to combine the images (it can read SVGs directly, but it's not so good at rendering them). Here's an example:

---

**graph.tif:**
[image: graph without grid]

---

**grid.tif:**
[image: grid image]

---

**command line syntax:**

```
composite -compose Multiply graph.tif grid.tif graph2.tif
```

---

**Result (grid2.tif):**
[image: combined graph plus grid]

---

You can use command line scripting to apply the same grid to multiple images, e.g.:

```
for (( i=1; i<=4; i++ )) do
    composite -compose Multiply graph-$i.tif grid.tif graph2-$i.tif
done
```

This will add grids to images called graph-1.tif, graph-2.tif. graph-3.tif etc. in the current directory, and save the results as graph2-1.tif, graph2-2.tif. graph2-3.tif etc.

Comment: Got it! for i in *.tif;  do composite -compose Multiply "$i" Grid.tiff "grid-$i";done

Comment: One problem: The grid are a bit larger, and I want the picture in the middle of the grid, now its in the top left corner. Maybe I should remake it

Comment: Try adding `-gravity Center` to the options

Comment: You must be the nicest person alive. Thank you very much!